# Approach for creating consolidated trace/ logs for on-premises solution consuming Azure services

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, servicebus

Following is the proposed transition in our application:

- Web Application is deployed in on-premises IIS (Web Server 1).
- Web Application has one functionality (for example, Generate Invoice for selected customer).
- For each new request of Generate Invoice, the web application is writing message to the Azure Service Bus Queue.
- Azure function gets triggered for each new message in Azure Service Bus Queue.
- Azure function triggers Web API (deployed on-premises).
- Web API generates Invoice for the customer and stores in the local file storage.

As of now, we have everything setup on-premises, and instead of Service Bus and Azure function, we directly consume Web API. With this type of infrastructure in place, we are currently logging all events in an MongoDB collection, and providing single consolidated view to the user. So they can identify what happened to the Generate Invoice request, and at which level and with which error it got failed (in case of failures).

With the new proposed architecture, we are in process of identifying ways for logging and tracing here, and display consolidated view to the users.

The only option, I can think of is to log all events in Azure Cosmos DB from everywhere (i.e., Website, Service bus, function, Web API), and then provide consolidated view.

Can anyone suggest if the suggested approach looks OK? Or if anyone has some better solution?

Comment: I suggest using Application Insights

Comment: As @PeterBons said, use application insights, you can build consolidate view as describe here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/overview#application-insights) monitors the availability, performance, and usage of your web applications **whether they're hosted in the cloud or on-premises**. It leverages the powerful data analysis platform in Azure Monitor to provide you with deep insights into your application's operations and diagnose errors without waiting for a user to report them.

Workbooks combine data visualizations, Analytics queries, and text into interactive documents. **You can use workbooks to group together** common usage information, consolidate information from a particular incident, or report back to your team on your application's usage.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-users#consolidate-usage-data).